# Exposing .NET class field through COM

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, com, com-interop

I am attempting to re-use a repository in some classic ASP legacy code. I've tagged my UnitOfWork class with ComVisible(true) and made a factory to create an instance of UnitOfWork. However, when I attempt to call the repository field in my UnitOfWork class through COM in classic ASP I get an error message stating "Object is required".

I have a feeling that COM "doesn't understand" that an object is returned by the getter in this case. I would prefer to avoid writing up a repository factory for just this situation.

```
Microsoft VBScript-kjøretidsfeil error '800a01a8'

Krever objekt: 'workorderRepository'

/test/test.asp, line 44
```

Classic ASP code:

```
Dim uowFactory, unitOfWork
Dim workorderRepository

Set uowFactory = CreateObject("Infrastructure.UOWFactory")
Set unitOfWork = uowFactory.CreateUnitOfWork(GetConnectionString())
Set workorderRepository = unitOfWork.WorkorderRepository

workorderRepository.GetAll() <- This is where the error occurs.
```

C# code:

```
public EfWorkorderRepository WorkorderRepository
{
    get
    {
        return this._workorderRepository ?? (this._workorderRepository = new EfWorkorderRepository(this._context));
    }
}
```

Apologies in advance if there is some code I've not thought to include. Leave a comment and I'll add it.

Comment: Are you sure that `workorderRepository` is the object it's referring to? What does `.GetAll()` do, can you include that?